# Test Flow using statIn With MVVM not update data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

How are you
I have flow converted to StateIn using extension fun I apply these steps from official document
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test#statein

Here is My codes

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val chatRepository: ChatRepository,
    private val messageRepository: MessageRepository,
    private val dispatchers :DispatcherProvider
) : ViewModel() {
    val homeState = chatRepository.getChats().map {
        HomeChatState(it)
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), HomeChatState())

    fun addTestChat(chat: Chat) {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatchers.io) {
            chatRepository.insertChat(
                chat
            )
        }
    }
```

and this fake repo

```
class FakeChatRepo:ChatRepository {
    private val chats = MutableStateFlow<List<Chat>>(emptyList())
    override fun getChats(): Flow<List<Chat>> {
        return chats.asStateFlow()
    }

    override suspend fun insertChat(chat: Chat) {
        chats.emit(chats.value + chat)
    }

    override suspend fun deleteChatById(chat: Chat) {
        chats.value -= chat
    }

    override suspend fun readMessages(chatId: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

and this test codes

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val messageRepo = MessageFakeRepository()
        val chatRepo = FakeChatRepo()
        val testDispatcher = TestDispatcherProvider()
        homeViewModel = HomeViewModel(chatRepo, messageRepo, testDispatcher)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun addChat_returnTrue() = runTest {
        val chat =
            Chat(
                1,
                "sender test",
                "test",
                "salman",
                "Hi",
                "",
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                1,
                "hi"
            )
        val s = homeViewModel.homeState

        backgroundScope.launch(UnconfinedTestDispatcher(testScheduler)) {
            s.collect()
        }
        Truth.assertThat(s.value.chats).isEmpty()
        homeViewModel.addTestChat(chat) // here is issue not update data and always retrun empty valye
        Truth.assertThat(s.value.chats).containsExactly(chat)

    }
}
```

the problem is when add data from addTestChat() it is not working as except
Thanks

Comment: Your `addTestChat` function is asynchronous so you’re checking the value before it has had a chance to be changed. It’s a race condition.

Comment: you should set coroutines rule like in NowInAndroid test

Comment: Ok I will try and I will update you

Comment: I solved this just add Dispatcher.setMain() rule and works